# Is it possible to host a *CONSOLE* application in AWS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to upload a .net console application, which has selenium in it which does some automation in the web.
I have seen the docs that tell us how to upload a mvc application and i have hosted it successfully.
So the question is, is it possible to upload a console application created in visual studio to aws.

Comment: Why don't you contact AWS support and ask them the question directly ?

Comment: will do that too, is there any other option

Comment: Of course it is possible. You can have either linux or windows VM with your app running on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon EC2 creates a virtual machine that runs the operating system of your choice.

You can run whatever you wish on it, as long as it does not violate the Terms & Conditions of usage.

Comment: Created an instance and using it, the console app is working good, but now i have a problem with my scheduler in the Virtual machine, which is not relevant to the question i asked, thanks anyways for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy it to AWS Lightsail or AWS EC2 . But you are in developing some application, it is better to deploy to AWS Lightsail as to reduce cost of development.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Possible it will be very easy, I hope. In my case I use .NetCore 3.1 console app, where I implement tcplistener, tcpClient.

1. Configure port in aws.
2. when u create instances u will see public ipv4 address, that u will put in yours
   client or app file.
3. and after than in that instance open cmd -> type ipconfig -> thane u find private
   ipv4 address, that use in server file.

   Finished!!!

Comment: What kind of aws service are you using to have tcplistener?

Answer (score -1):

Literally you don't need AWS to host your console app at all, as you can write even simpler [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/features/) in C#, which is similar to Azure Functions.

Comment: do you think lambda can be used for scheduling it continuously, i dont have much xp in aws, if so just holler some simple steps, ll catch on to it